# MySQL whitelist query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a custom white list, where my main table is book_list, containing id - primary key, and other columns which are unimportant. Another table is whitelist which contains a foreign key from book_list and another key which is user_id.

book_list table

```
--------------
| id          |
---------------
| 10          |
| 11          |
| 12          |
| 13          |
---------------
```

whitelist table

```
---------------------------
| book_list_id   | user_id |
----------------------------
| 10             | 1       |
| 10             | 2       |
----------------------------
```

So when user_id 1 is browsing, he/she should see all the books (10, 11, 12, 13), but if user with id 5 looks he should see just book_list ids (11, 12, 13)

My query was something like this, but it works if just one id per book_id is available.

```
SELECT * FROM book_list bl
LEFT JOIN whitelist w ON bl.id = w.book_list_id AND w.user_id <> 1
WHERE w.book_list_id IS NULL
```

Note: I always have the user_id from session that why it is hard coded.

Comment: I think you'll need some sort of subquery to check if the `user_id` exists for that `W.book_list_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM book_list
LEFT JOIN whitelist
  ON (whitelist.book_list_id = book_list.id)
WHERE (COALESCE(whitelist.user_id, 1) = 1)
```

**Edited to include explanation**

The conditional performs two things at once. If there are no records in `whitelist` for the book, then the `COALESCE` function will return the user's id. If there are records in `whitelist` for the book, then the conditional will prevent any matches occurring unless the user's id is attached to that book.

Comment: Thank you! Quite simple and powerful at the same time.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. But keep in mind that if this will cause a bug if the user with ID 1 exists. Instead, I would use a different number outside of the range of possible user ID like 0 or -1.

Comment: Actually, the `1` would be a parameter to the query and you would use whatever `user_id` is appropriate for the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired query actually consists of two different sets of results: 1) books that have no whitelist defined and 2) books that have a whitelist but the current user has access. To get the correct result, you need to break these two parts down and then UNION them at the end.

```
SELECT distinct bl.id FROM book_list bl 
LEFT JOIN whitelist w1 ON bl.id = w1.book_list_id AND w.user_id <> 1
INNER JOIN whitelist w2 ON bl.id = w2.book_list_id AND w.user_id = 1
WHERE w1.book_list_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT distinct bl.id FROM book_list bl 
LEFT JOIN whitelist w ON bl.id = w.book_list_id
WHERE w.book_list_id IS NULL
```

The first query excludes all books not whitelisted for user 1 and includes all books whitelisted for user 1. The second query returns all the books that have no whitelist.